# AD on Windows Server 2012 + Windows LDAP + PHP Bind

Tags: php, ldap

I've set up Active Directory and ADLDAP on Windows server 2012.  I'm trying a simple ldap_bind but continue to have a "invalid credentials" error spit back to me.

In my AD Users and Groups screen, I clearly see the domain I made along with the OU (organizational unit) and users inside of it. ASDI Edit clearly tells me the DN for that user:

```
CN=Bob Smith,OU=Accounting,DC=mydomain,DC=net
```

Further, the BaseDN is clearly told to me in ASDI Edit because it's above the OU group "accounting" -

```
DC=mydomain,DC=net
```

Now onto my script - which throws no LDAP connect errors, only on bind, with a constant invalid credentials:

```
$connectionLDAP = "LDAP://localhost:54126"; 
$basedn = 'DC=mydomain,DC=net';
$ldap = ldap_connect($connectionLDAP) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
$username = $post['username'];
$password = $post['password'];
$usernameForBind = "CN=".$username.",OU=Accounting,".$basedn;
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
$bind = ldap_bind($ldap, $usernameForBind, $password);
```

This spits the following warning, and of course my script ends there since there is no positive match to username and password found:

```
Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials in C:\....\login.php on line 41
```

And the below error echos produce this:

```
echo(ldap_error($ldap)."<br>");
echo(ldap_errno($ldap)."<br>");


Invalid credentials
49
```

I have tried every combination of DN, username, email address, mydomain\username without the rest of the DN info, everything I can think of....but for the life of me it won't take, and google + Stack searches unfortunately aren't helping me at the moment get past this.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: why are you using localhost in the ldap query?

Comment: At the moment the AD and the LDAP and the PHP script are all on the same machine, just for development.  I have also tried replacing that with my server address and the same port, still no luck.  The connection seems to be fine from what I can tell... no errors or warnings thrown.

Comment: ok - it's just that in the past when I have connected to ldap via php I used the fqdn of the dc as the base to the ldap query - though to be fair I had AD running on virtual machines rather than essentially the same host but still, try with the full dns name of the dc and I supplied the port as the second parameter to ldap_connect

Comment: @RamRaider unbelievable.  LOL.  I think moving the port number to the second parameter is really what did it.  THANK YOU.

Comment: no problem - good luck with the rest !

Answer (score 0):

You are using Active directory on Windows, So please change your code to following It would work. Because AD need **@domain_name** as username suffix in bind function.

```
$connectionLDAP = "ldap://localhost"; 
$basedn = '@mydomain.net';
$ldap = @ldap_connect($connectionLDAP, 54126) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
$username = $post['username'];
$password = $post['password'];
$usernameForBind = $username.$basedn;
@ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
@ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
$bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $usernameForBind, $password);
```

**I've tested such scenarios many times, It works for AD.**

And also Please make sure that your AD server is running on the same port you're using in code ie. 54126.